# Opera: polyfill for the HTML5 menu tag with type: command

Tags: html, menu, command, opera, polyfills

Anyone know of one?  Firefox and Chrome get it right; Opera just displays a square +.

Comment: consider adding jsfiddle with example code to get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for a polyfill anymore; the latest dev build of Opera brings support.  :)